# How to fix this error please - TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, sql, json, sql-server, sql-server-2019

In my case the JSON file which I need to insert into database is already stored in variable named "data" i.e `data = res.read()`.

I need to insert that "data" into the database directly where my database name called Rest and table called `bms`. It is getting connected to database. But I am getting the below error. I need help please

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\trees\RESTAPI_Python_Code\Test2.py", line 70, in 
> cursor.execute(('INSERT INTO dbo.bms([Value],[Unit],[WatchName])'),(json.dumps(data)))
> File "C:\Python310\lib\json_init.py", line 231, in dumps
> return default_encoder.encode(obj)
> File "C:\Python310\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
> chunks = self.iterencode(o, one_shot=True)
> File "C:\Python310\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
> return iterencode(o, 0)
> File "C:\Python310\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
> raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.class.name} '
> TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable

My code is below

```
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("120.157.117.168:8443")
payload = ''
headers = {
  'Authorization': f'Bearer {bearer_token}'
}
conn.request("GET", "/api/watches/AHU1%20Control", payload, headers)
#conn.request("GET", "/watches/AHU1%20Control", payload, headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
print(data.decode("utf-8"))


cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server};"
                      "Server=DESKTOP-9KT0GQV;"
                      "Database=Rest;"
                      "Trusted_Connection=yes;")
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

cursor.execute(('INSERT INTO dbo.bms([Value],[Unit],[WatchName])'),(json.dumps(data)))

for row in cursor:
    print(row)

cursor.close()
cnxn.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your object is a bytes object. You need to `decode()` it first (as you did in the print) before trying to serialize (`json.dumps()`) it.

Comment: Yes your right its in bytes and that print one is in dict. I tried converting bytes ti dict. Its not working.